# Visual Studio 2017 UI ignores CSPROJ <PackageVersion>

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I have a simple .NetCoreApp 1.1 Class Library, currently open in Visual Studio 2017 15.2 (26430.13).
I'd like to create a NuGet package on build, and have configured the "Package" tab of my project settings; including the "Generate NuGet package on build".
On that tab I set the "**Package id**" and "**Package version**".
I see the **Package id** stored in the CSPROJ`<PackageId>` element.
However, I do not see the Package version being stored in the `<PackageVersion>` element. 
The NuGet package gets built using the CSPROJ`<PackageVersion>` value; and the different value shown in the project properties "Package" tab is stored in some magical location I cannot find.

Is this a bug?

-John

Answer (score 1):

The `PackageVersion` is defaulted to `Version` if it isn't set explicitly in the project itself, so editing `Version` alone will also set the resulting nuget package's version. In addition, `Version` - in contrast to `PackageVersion` - will also be used as a default for the autogenerated AssemblyInfo.cs so in many cases, you'd want to set `Version` anyway to affect both assembly metadata **and** the nuget's package version.

If you think that this behaviour is incorrect - especially when you define a custom `PackageVersion` in the project itself - this can be considered a bug, or a missing feature for the case when you set `PackageVersion` manually. You could open an issue on the [project system's GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues) to discuss this behaviour.

Comment: If you are setting AssemblyVersion and FileVersion in the csproj then using Version instead of PackageVersion would essentially do nothing then, correct?

Comment: In case it wasn't clear to others, what worked for me was just deleting the <PackageVersion> entry in my csproj -- my package was then built with <Version>, which is what you actually edit in the UI.